# Can the Sliding tabs sample provided on android developers site be used in development of commercial apps?

Tags: android

Hi can we use the sliding tabs samples provided by Google on their developers site in  commercial apps given that it is licensed under Apache Version 2.0.If so what part of the source code will need to be made public if I use the sliding tab layout file in my app.
Here is the link to the sliding tab sample.

https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in a commercial app without making any part of your source code or your modifications to Google's code public. The Apache 2.0 license is permissive - as opposed to the viral GPL license - and allows use without source code publication.